# How to exclude a tag from an html file with xidel?

Tags: html, parsing, xidel

How to extract **text1** from the following file using xidel?

```
<html>
<body>
        <div class="class1">
                text1
                <table><tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>t1tr1td1</td>
                    <td>t1tr1td2</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xidel file.html -e "//div/text()"
```

Comment: This will extract 2 text-nodes and a lot of whitespace. To extract just "text1" (from the 1st text-node) you'd better use `//div/normalize-space(text()[1])`